# object is not in legend when changing color of line in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, time-series

This is my code:

```
clist <- list(c(1:39), c(2:40), c(3:41))
clist.ts <- lapply(clist, function(x) ts(x, frequency = 1, start = 1978))
ind78_ymean_tsdf <- as.data.frame(clist.ts)
names(ind78_ymean_tsdf) <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")
ind78_ymean_tsdf$"Year" <- c(1978:2016)

(ggplot(ind78_ymean_tsdf, aes(x=Year)) 
  + geom_line(aes(y=name1, color="Name One") ) 
  + geom_line(aes(y=name2, color="Name Two") ) 
  + geom_line(aes(y=name3), color="black", size=1.5 ) 
  + labs(title="Development of the indices", x="Year", y="Index") 
  + scale_color_discrete(name="Individual replications"))
```

Unfortunately after changing the `name3` variable color to black it somehow is not anymore displayed in the legend. I would like to change that, but don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

ps. thats how the plot looks like:

[image]

Comment: The respective line in your code should be `+ geom_line(aes(y=name3, color="black"), size=1.5 )`. Put the `color` argument inside `aes()` as you have done in the previous two lines. However, instead of calling `geom_line` three times, a better way would be to [reshape your data from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361455/converting-a-dataframe-from-wide-format-to-long-format-in-r/19361581#19361581).

Comment: If you put it in the `aes()` something really strange happens. Let it run and see for yourself, cant really describe it :) And I know about reshaping my data, but then it is even more complicated manually change a color or shape of only one variable!

Comment: btw, the `color` command in the `aes()` only changes the name in the legend and if its outside the `aes()` then it changes the color.

Comment: Yannick, you can try this: `library(tidyr); gather(ind78_ymean_tsdf, key, value, 1:3) %>% ggplot(aes(Year, value, col = key, size = key)) + geom_line() + scale_color_manual("Individual replications", values = c(name1 = "red", name2 = "blue", name3 = "black")) + scale_size_manual("Individual replications", values = c(name1 = .5, name2 = .5, name3 = 1.5))`

Comment: ok, thanks! looks good, but I was already at a similar point when I used `melt`, but my real plot has 14 variables, thus it is a bit annoying to pick all the rainbow colors for my variables by hand. isn't there a way to change only one color and let ggplot do the rest in the rainbow colors?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896039/ggplot-manual-color-assignment-for-single-variable-only and also check out the [`gghighlight`](https://yutani.rbind.io/post/2017-10-06-gghighlight/) package.

Comment: Yesss! this is exactly what I am looking for! thanks a lot! do you know how i had to change the following line in order to get the line in the legend also black: `guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(
    colour=c(hue_pal()(11)[1:10], "black"), size=c(rep(1, 10), 1.5))))`. I have 13 variables if that helps.. :)